# How to speed up the loading time of svg icons on vue 3

Tags: vue.js, svg, vue-component, vuejs3, web-frontend

I have svg icons that are conditionally rendered on vue component. The idea is to change the colour of the icon when the mouse hover over the icon, the icons are exactly the same except for colour.

I have built vue3 SPA project with *cli*, both *svg* icons are stored in *assets* folder of the *src* file.
Here is the code for conditionally rendering icons.

```html
<div
  class="icons"
  v-on:mouseover="hoverMenu = true"
  v-on:mouseout="hoverMenu = false"
>
  <img
    v-if="!hoverMenu"
    title="Menu"
    src="../assets/help_outline_24px.svg"
    alt="icon"
  />
  <img
    v-else-if="hoverMenu"
    title="Menu"
    src="../assets/help_24px.svg"
    alt="icon"
  />
</div>
```

Data binding

```js
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      hoverMenu: null,
    }
  },
}
```

The code runs and the icons change when hover over icons however the are two issues.

1. The first time user hover over the icon it takes longer to load the icon, there is a split or few seconds before the icon changes, by that time it is substituted by *alt* element text.
2. Sometimes the icons don't change when the mouse hover over icons repeatedly, e.g when mouse hover over icon it changes then it does't change back when mouse is out of icon as if the condition has not changed at all.

Please assist with the issues above, I'm still new to front-end and vue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How large are the SVG files, have you tried an extremely simple one?

Comment: About 4kb, I have tried with simple help icon.

Comment: And did it change anything? And for 24px squared you 1kb should be sufficient, otherwise you could try a png instead of a svg?

Comment: Nothing changed, is 4kb too big for this task?

Comment: A 24px x 24px RGB bitmap has 1728 bytes, 4kb is a lot for 576 pixels. But on the other hand it is nothing for a modern computer. You could try inlining it, so the file does not have to be loaded from disk. Basically paste the svg code into the html  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Comment: You are swapping <img>  why not only make the ``src=`` dynamic... that's less work for the Browser. And instead of ``mouseover`` use ``mouseenter``

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I have used inline SVG as suggested by @WolfgangBrehm. Instead of loading icon as <img> element I have converted the svg code into vue template and change the color via css. Loading and response time has improved significantly. Thanks a lot.